# Install Serialport module on NodeJS (mac) for Johnny-Five

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, node-serialport, johnny-five

I'm not able to install module Serialport on Mac. Therefore it's not possible to connect Arduino through Johnny-five with my computer. It says this error:

```
gyp: /Users/me/.node-gyp/4.0.0/common.gypi not found (cwd: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:357:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/serialport.node" "--module_name=serialport" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.7
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport/build/serialport/v1.7.4/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64' (1)
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "serialport" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! serialport@1.7.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@1.7.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the serialport package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls serialport
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried to install it locally, globally, look up the solution, but nothing helped. Maybe because I recently updated to NodeJS 4.0.0. But I tried to downgrade it and the result was still the same. Visual Studio and Python (version 2.x) is installed (which was suggested in many not working "solutions").

Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i've the same issue. a colleague told me that using NVM might work. i'm working on that now

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer, Node-Serialport does not support Node 4.x.  You'll need to install 0.12.x or 0.10.x.  Follow [this issue](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/578) for details.